Creating a Repeating/Looped Table in Cognos
I need to create a table of lat/lon coordinates with repeating values, in order to calculate distances between all locations.
In the DB I have the following fields to use:



Location Code
Latitude
Longitude




ABC123
39.426413
-77.458716


DEF456
25.708686
-80.378430


ZYX123
38.734117
-77.473075



What I'd like to do is have each location repeat in column 1, with column 2 having all the other locations.



Location Code 1
Location Code 2
Lat 1
Lon 1
Lat 2
Lon 2




ABC123
ABC123
39.426413
-77.458716
39.426413
-77.458716


ABC123
DEF456
39.426413
-77.458716
25.708686
-80.378430


ABC123
ZYX123
39.426413
-77.458716
38.734117
-77.473075


DEF456
ABC123
25.708686
-80.378430
39.426413
-77.458716


DEF456
DEF456
25.708686
-80.378430
25.708686
-80.378430


DEF456
ZYX123
25.708686
-80.378430
38.734117
-77.473075



etc.
Is there a way to do a Union or Join to get this kind of query setup?
I've tried a few different types of joins and nothing seems to be coming out like I'm looking for it to.  Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

It's not a loop.  You are not using structured programming to solve the problem.  You are using Cognos Analytics, which deals with data.  So what you need is a way to appropriately join the dataset to itself.
Use a CROSS JOIN, also known as a cartesian join.  This is a join where you don't relate the tables in any way.  So rather than something like...
SELECT A.*
, B.*
FROM A
  INNER JOIN B ON B.ID = A.ID

...you want this...
SELECT A.*
, B.*
FROM A
  CROSS JOIN B

To to this in a Cognos Analytics report:
Let's assume you have a query named Query1.

Copy Query1.  Query2 is created.
Create a new query (Query3).
Add a join to Query3.
Drag Query1 and Query2 onto the boxes leading to the join.
Open Query3 and add data items as needed.

Notice you did NOT define the join.
Now, there's a setting in Cognos that may keep you from doing this.  If you get a message stating that cross joins are not allowed, you need to do a little extra work.

In Query1 and Query2, create a data item named joincol and use the expression 'a'.
Open the join leading to Query3 and create a join on joincol--joincol.


Thanks for the quick response.  I ended up doing another work around to have the join setup with a custom expression "Location <> Location OR Location = Location."

Interesting.  That should work.  I'm pretty sure I tried the expression 1=1, but it didn't fool Cognos.  Cognos still recognized it as a cross join.
